# Are there any problems with file-names containing . in some OS?

Tags: operating-system, filenames

Are there any problems with file-names containing . on some OS? For example "**my.program.settings.properties**"? Is this a valid file name on windows **and** on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid under Windows, Linux and most modern OSes but invalid under some older OSes like MSDOS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `my.program.settings.properties` is a valid filename on Windows, Linux and Unix (Style) operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

It is worthwhile to make the distinction of decoupling the file system from the OS.  A modern OS typically will not have a problem with this.  However, the file system (such as FAT) that the OS is using may.